# Order of functions calls

Tags: c++

Is it guaranteed that the `make_string` object will be constructed before the call to `GetLastError` function in the following code:

```
class make_string
{
public:
  template <typename T>
  make_string& operator<<(const T& arg)
  {
    _stream << arg;
    return *this;
  }

  operator std::string() const
  {
    return _stream.str();
  }

protected:
  std::ostringstream _stream;
};

// Usage
foo(make_string() << GetLastError());
```

Comment: @101010, what is the member function and why is it important?

Comment: @SergeyA `make_string::operator<<` is a member of `class make_string`. For this specific example `make_string::operator<<` to be evoked first `make_string()` constructor must be called.

Comment: @101010, why? nothing prevents compiler from first calling `GetLastError()` and than constructing `make_string` object.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes you're right, I was confused with evocation of overloaded member operator `operator<<` and construction of the object. `GetLastError()` can be called any time.

Comment: @FrozenHeart: Why are you selecting as solution an answer that just claims, incorrectly, that the problem that [you linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37687747/order-of-functions-calls/37687877#comment62852656_37687762) can't happen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not guranteed. `make_string() << GetLastError()` is semantically equivalent to the function call `operator<<( make_string(), GetLastError() )`, and order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified.

So, the compiler can first create an instance of `make_string`, then call `GetLastError()`, and then call a member function of said `make_string` object, or it could first call `GetLastError()`, then create an instance, and then call the member function. In my experience, the second outcome is more likely.

**EDIT**

There is also an interesting question raised couple of times in comments, which I believe is worth addressing.

The claim is, that since `operator<<` is a member function, the whole statement is semantically the same as

```
make_string().operator<<(GetLastError());
```

This claim is, indeed, true. However, there is no sequencing in the above statement! What happens first - `GetLastError()` call or `make_sequence` constructor is undefined because of lack of sequencing here.

Comment: Unfortunately it *does* matter. GetLastError should be called immediately after the corresponding WinAPI function. See here -- https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1775690/calling-operator-new-may-set-lasterror-to-0

Comment: @FrozenHeart, I am aware of that, but I do not see any calls to any WinApi functions in your example.

Comment: And I don't quite understand your answer. It's not about comparing `operator<<` and `GetLastError` function call, it's about comparing `make_string` constructor and `GetLastError` function call

Comment: @SergeyA I've edited your answer but I'm not sure it's better. What do you think?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I have a question -- why do you say that `make_string() << GetLastError()` is the equivalent of `operator<<(make_string(), GetLastError()` and not `make_string().operator<<(GetLastError())`?

Comment: @FrozenHeart That was me, and you're right: This isn't really about function arguments but about the order of evaluation of X/Y in `X.foo(Y)`. The outcome is the same, though: C++ doesn't specify the order of evaluation of most expressions.

Comment: @SergeyA Why do you think so? Why is it a free function call instead of a member function call?

Comment: @melpomene So the order of `X` and `Y` doesn't specified even for expressions like `X.foo(Y)`?

Comment: @FrozenHeart, or, if you wanna know gory details, it is actually all but guranteed to be GetLastError() first, followed by constructor. At least on Intel platform.

Comment: "your make_string() constructor doesn't call any WinAPI functions", well, it **can**. There is an `ostringstream` data member, and its constructor may do a dynamic allocation, which may end up calling an API level allocation function.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, you are certainly free to downvote. However, I do not agree with you. **ANY** potential WinAPI error in given code would be resulting in C++ exception. There is no way this error can happen and the execution will continue. I stand my ground your downvote notwithstanding.

Comment: @SergeyA: It doesn't need to be a failure. Any function is free to call `SetLastError(0)`, for example; Microsoft even notes this in the documentation, that "Most functions call SetLastError or SetLastErrorEx only when they fail. However, some system functions call SetLastError or SetLastErrorEx under conditions of success; those cases are noted in each function's documentation." . Consider also that failures can happen internally and can be handled internally without this being in any way evident to the user code, except for side effects such as the result of `GetLastError`. So, please fix.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, ok, I see your point. Removed this line, since it was never really a punchline of my message.

Answer (score 3):

The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified.

And `make_string() << GetLastError()` is a call of the `operator<<` function.

However, in order to guarantee that `GetLastError` is called after a Windows API function, in a creation of an error message, you can use the built-in `||` operator, like this:

```
AnApiFunctionThatReturnsTrueOnSuccess()
    || fail( "Bah, it failed", GetLastError() );
```

The order of evaluation is guaranteed here because the built-in `||` has short circuit behavior. The right hand side argument is only evaluated if the left hand argument evaluates to `false`.

Then the `fail` function can look like

```
auto fail( std::string const& s, int const code = 0 )
    -> bool
{
    throw std::runtime_error( make_string() << s << " (code = " << code << ")" );
}
```

doing the **`make_string()`** at a point guaranteed after `GetLastError()`, so that any call to e.g. an API level allocation function won't invalidate the result from `GetLastError`.

Answer (score 1):

An overloaded `<<` is just a function call, and order of evaluation in unspecified.  In your case, the ctor of your `make_string` is empty (other than constructing an oss), so it does not matter: in your real code, this probably is not true.

A way around this is:

```
foo(make_string() << [&]{return GetLastError();});
```

then:

```
template<class T> struct tag{using type=T;};
```

and in the object:

```
template<class F>
make_string& operator<<(const F& arg)
{
  output(arg, std::result_of<F const&()>{});
  return *this;
}
template<class F, class Test>
tag<typename Test::type> output(F const& f, Test const&) {
  _stream << f();
  return {};
}
template<class T, class...Unused>
void output(T const& t, Unused const&...) {
  _stream << t;
}
```

where if we are passed a callable, we invoke it.

This is manual short-circuit evaluation.

Some of the code above may contain typos or similar errors: the design is sound.  It assumes `result_of` is SFINAE enabled, as C++14 demands.  There are other ways to detect if something can be invoked with 0 arguments if your `result_of` fails.

Comment: This guarantees that `make_string()` is evaluated before `GetLastError()`, which is the wrong order, as I understand it. The problem is that a call to an API level allocation function can invalidate the result from `GetLastError()`. But I don't understand the wording in the question.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf "wrong"?  It is the order the OP asked for.

Comment: I revised my comment adding explanation. The OP's request doesn't make sense to me.